# Express js, app.post not receiving connection

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I'm trying to create an application with NodeJS and I stumbled upon a problem. I use Postman to check the post request, but the server never enters the function. 
GET requests work fine.
What can I do to fix this?

part of the code:

```
app.use(reloadify);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false}));


app.locals.basedir = "static";
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));

app.post('/api/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log('received');
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log("Listening");
    console.log(__dirname);
});
```

**EDIT:**
It seems the reloadify module blocks the post request. Commenting this one out makes it work. Changing the question to how I can make both of them work.

**Edit 2:**
It was a bug in reloadify, I made a new branch and fixed it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you paste your whole code here?

Comment: What is reloadify? Is it your local module?

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon reloadify is a module that refreshes the browser when static files have changed.
https://github.com/alessioalex/reloadify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloadify has a bug, it only allows HTTP: GET and HEAD methods trough the express middleware. For Express js, [editing the middleware function to go to the next layer fixes it](https://github.com/BlockCat/reloadify/commit/b27b38ae3448090bb06ac400234534038410356f).

I hope I'm using the correct terminologie.